# LCD screen of Canon showing black in auto mode

Tags: canon, lcd, lens-cap

I accidently left the cap of the lens on the camera when I turned it on, however for some reason the LCD screen was just black when I finally took the cap off. When I go to photo preview the photos are fine, so the camera is taking the pictures just not showing me the preview on the screen. When I change from auto mode to C1 mode it shows me the preview, but it does not show me the preview in any other mode. How can I fix that ?

Comment: What camera is this specifically? Does the LCD screen show you menus and other information? When you say "preview", do you mean the live view which lets you frame the shot, or do you mean review _after_ you've taken an image?

Comment: Yes I mean the review after I have taken the image, it is a Canon EOS Rebel T5. When the camera is in auto mode it does not show any menu or other information, it is just black. It happened right after I tried to turn it on with the cap on. The camera is taking pictures and I can see it just fine on the review it is just the LCD screen that is black. When I put it in any other mode except C1 it also shows as black. C1 and C2 are the only modes it shows the image on the screen before I take the picture. Thank you for responding.

Comment: The Rebel T5 has no *C1* or *C2* on the mode dial.

Answer (score 3):

Whether an image is automatically displayed or not following capture can be turned on or off using the menu on all digital Canon EOS cameras. If you have selected a setting that displays the image, you can also select from several options that determine for how long the review image is displayed. You may have turned it off without realizing what you were doing. The reason you see it when in the C1 mode is that the C1 mode was set up before you accidently changed the setting. When you turn the dial to C1 it uses the settings active at the time you recorded the then-current settings to C1.¹

You can turn image review on or off using the *Shooting1 (red)* menu tab of your camera's menu. From page 180 of the *[EOS Rebel T5/1200D Instruction Manual](https://www4.uwm.edu/psoa_er/manuals/cameras/CanonT5.pdf)*:

[image]

To control when the settings appear on the screen, use the *Setup2 (yellow)* menu tab of your camera's menu. From page 193 of the *Manual*:

[image]

For *Live View*, please be sure you have *Live View* enabled under the last tab of the *Shooting (red)* menu:

[image]

<sub>¹ This, of course, requires a Canon camera that offers user configurable "Custom" modes on the mode dial. The EOS Rebel T5/1200D does not include this feature.</sub>

Comment: But when I turn it to video mode, or frame mode it also shows it as black, the only mode that does not is C1 and C2. The camera I use is Canon EOS Rebel T5. I was just taking regular pictures for work. This happened right after I tried to turn the camera on and didn't realize the cap was still on, when I took off the cap the screen was black, I tried taking a picture and it worked fine but I could only see the picture when I pressed the review picture button. Thank you for replying.

Comment: What happens when you press the *Menu* button?

Comment: Please see the edits I've made to my answer. P.S. - The cap being on when you turned the camera on has nothing to do with it.

Comment: There is no *C1* or *C2* option on the Rebel T5.

Comment: Is this also for a Canon PowerShot G16? my display screen is black! (Turning the Display monitor on and off....)...I don't think so?